# Convert object received from server into object with ko observable properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am having issues with what seemed like an easy idea.

I am trying to create `ko.observable()`'s dynamically from server provided data.

The server is sending me a ~240 value JSON array. I want to create an observable for each one as I am putting them into an online form.

#### First try

```
function AppViewModel() {

  var self = this;

  var data = {};

  $.getJSON("/record/20001", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
      self.data[i] = ko.observable(val);
    });
  });


  self.test = 5;

  self.test2 = ko.observable(69);


}

vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

With this I was unable to access any of the data.

#### Second try which worked

```
function AppViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.abnorm_comment = ko.observable();
    self.abnorm_test1 = ko.observable();
    self.abo_sys_spec = ko.observable();
    self.access_location = ko.observable();
    self.ace_inhibit = ko.observable();

    /* 
    A myriad of line like these, written by hand
    */

    self.xray_other = ko.observable();


    $.getJSON("/record/20001", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            self[i](val);
        });
    });

    self.test = 5;

    self.test2 = ko.observable(69);


}
```

#### What I am trying to do

```
function AppViewModel() {

    var self = this;

    var data = {};


    $.getJSON("/record/20001", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            self.data[i] = ko.observable(val);
        });
    });

}
```

And access it like so:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: data.case_id">
```

For the first try my view model has no data in it. If I pull up the `vm` variable in the Chrome console it does have the data though.

Am I doing something wrong here? The second way that works does not look very nice with so many observables.

Please let me know if I am missing something obvious

### Personal Solution

It ended up that I was having a race condition between applying the bindings and the the AJAX server request. I also ended up using the plugin as recommended by @JotaBe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin which will do it for you.

The advantages are that this plugin is well tested, and is able to map more complex data, like arrays, or nested properties.

You can map from JSON, or from an already instanced JavaScript object. The synatx is as simple as this:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
```

Another advantage is that it can also update your local mapped copy from new updated data coming from the server, without rebuilding the whole object. This also helps in updating the view, without the need to rebuild (or unbind) it.

And a final advantage is taht it also allows to get back the JSON or JavaScript object if you need to post it back to the server, simply like this:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
```

Comment: What is the best way to add additional functionality to my ViewModel if I used the plugin? i.e. computed variables.

Comment: You can simply add the functionality later, on the created object. For example: `viewmodel.doubleX = ko.computed(function() { return 2*viewModel.x(); });` As you can see, you can access the properties by using the existing `viemodel` variable. In thsi case you can also use this pattern, as explained in the computed observable docs: `viewmodel.doubleX = ko.computed(function() { return 2*this.x(); }, viewModel);`

Comment: If you get into trouble, please, create a new question.

Comment: No that's great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This has worked reliably for me in the past:

```
jsonToObservable = function (obj, data) {

    for (var p in data) {
        var temp = data[p];

        obj[p] = ko.observable(temp);

    }
};
```

Comment: Beware: this solution will not correctly map arrays (if they come from the server) neither nested properties (if the server returns a nested object). So, this will only work from a simple object coming from the server, which only includes non-array properties..

Comment: @JotaBe The server only provides a simple object. So this will work. Thank you!